# No librabbitmq, while installing rabbitmq pecl brew php

Tags: php, rabbitmq, pecl

After deprecating homebrew-php, there is no amqp extension in brew native taps. I can't install amqp extension now.
PECL shows me this kind of error
`librabbitmq not found`

Where it can be found?

Answer (score 3):

This is `rabbitmq-c` also available in brew. 
Thanks